# Manual control over when to redraw the screen

Tags: c#, xna, xbox360, xna-4.0

I'm trying to make a turn-based roguelike engine thing for XNA. I'm basically porting the game over from a previous work I did using an SDL-based roguelike library called libtcod. How can I modify the basic XNA template thing to make the game *not* redraw the screen every frame, but, instead, when I want?

Comment: And why would you want to do that? Really, I'm curious.

Comment: Well, when you have a game whose graphics aren't changing until the user presses a key, it seems kind of silly to keep recalculating and redrawing everything over and over again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct method for doing this is to call `GraphicsDevice.Present()` whenever you want to draw the back buffer onto the screen.

Now the difficulty here is that the `Game` class automatically calls Present for you (specifically in `Game.EndDraw`), which is something you don't want it to do. Fortunately `Game` provides a number of ways to prevent Present from being called:

The best way would be to override `BeginDraw` and have it return false, to prevent a frame from being drawn (including preventing `Draw` and `EndDraw` from being called), like so:

```
protected override bool BeginDraw()
{
    if(readyToDraw)
        return base.BeginDraw();
    else
        return false;
}
```

The other alternatives are to call [`Game.SuppressDraw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.suppressdraw.aspx), or to override `EndDraw` such that it does not call `base.EndDraw()` until you are ready to have a frame displayed on screen.

Personally I would simply draw every frame.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to inherit from Game class, it is entirely optional. You can write your own class which redraws the screen only when you want. There's some useful code in the class though, so you can use Reflector to copy code from there and then change its logic.