# phone development and XNA/OpenGL: reduce battery consumption

Tags: monogame

I'm working on a wp7 xna application. As the app is not really a game (but needs to use XNA**) the screen does not change very often (menus, buttons etc.), mostly only when something gets touched. So  constant redrawing with 30fps or higher is not needed, only in some situations.

This posting shows how to
[control the Draw() frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054936/manual-control-over-when-to-redraw-the-screen/4057180#4057180) in a XNA game.

How much would the battery consumption be affected when reducing the framerate e.g. by the half ?
(**I'm also going to convert the app to Android/iOS using Monogame+ MonoDroid/MonoTouch (so i think OpenGL will be used then).

Any ideas/experiences on that ?

Comment: Is there a reason not to try it on an actual device and measure the difference?

Comment: No, but I just wanted to know if it is worth at all to spent time in developing a dynamic framerate adjustion and making measurements, in case it would already be "well known" whether the framerate has a noticeable effect on the battery